# Awkward Var-args argument

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Suppose this code:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.testInt(new int[]{2,3});
        Test.testInteger(new Integer[]{2,3});
    }

    public static void testInt(Object... elements){
      System.out.println(elements[0] instanceof int[]);
    }

    public static void testInteger(Object... elements){
      System.out.println(elements[0] instanceof Integer);
    }

}
```

In both cases, one expected to have a one-dimensional array which contains 2 and 3.
So the expected output should be at first sight:

```
false
true
```

Surprise! the real output is:

```
true
true
```

**UPDATE TO THIS POST:**

Actually, it is not a good question since I haven't realized that this case is in accordance with the Var-args rules.

To sum up, an int[] array cannot be autoboxed to Integer[] even when a Var-args is the argument; there's no exceptional treatment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't autobox a primitive array to an "wrapper" array: an array is a totally different type! There are some quite clear use cases for autoboxing primitives.  Those use cases don't exist for arrays.

Your method signature asks for at least one `Object`, and you supplied one: `int[]`.  Your method signature also allows you to provide an array, which you do with `Integer[]`.

It's also worth pointing out that all varargs methods can be invoked with arrays of the parameter type, which is what you're doing with `Integer`.  Since `int` isn't an `Object`, your compiler treats the **array** as an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks, I know it, I wasn't very clear, I have updated the post.

Comment: I totally agree with you but that didn't answer to my question :) My question is: why Java let the creation of a two-dimensional array with primitive array when passing to a var-args argument?

Comment: Updated.  See the third paragraph.